Want to hide the remove and edit button of formbuilder in @formio/react component
Image for reference
const Formio = dynamic(
  () => import("@formio/react").then((module) => module.Form),
  { ssr: false }
);

<Formio src={formJson}  onSubmit={submitHandler} onChange={handleFormChange}/>

@formio/react this is the library I am uisng in nextjs I want to hide or disable the remove and edit button of some of the form fields based on requirement how can I achieve it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is possible to do so by manipulating the Template.current using ctx. For example, if you want to enable only "Move" button in some components:
Templates.current = {
    builderComponent: {
        form:  `
        <div class="builder-component" ref="dragComponent">
          <div class="component-btn-group" data-noattach="true">
              {% if ( [some conditions]) { %}
              <div class="btn btn-xxs btn-default component-settings-button component-settings-button-move" ref="moveComponent">
                  <i class="{{ctx.iconClass('move')}}"></i>
              </div>
              {% } else { %}
              <div class="btn btn-xxs btn-danger component-settings-button component-settings-button-remove" ref="removeComponent">
                  <i class="{{ctx.iconClass('remove')}}"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="btn btn-xxs btn-default component-settings-button component-settings-button-move" ref="moveComponent">
                  <i class="{{ctx.iconClass('move')}}"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="btn btn-xxs btn-secondary component-settings-button component-settings-button-edit" ref="editComponent">
                  <i class="{{ctx.iconClass('cog')}}"></i>
              </div>

              {% } %}

          </div>
          {{ctx.html}}
        </div>`
    }
  };

You can obtain more information from FormIO's documentation.

UPDATE: For only blocking some of the elements, in the above [some condition] location, one possible way is simply by checking the types of the default components, for example:
{% if ( ctx.childComponent.type === "textArea" || 
  ctx.childComponent.type === "textField" ) %}

Or you can do the checking with other properties, e.g., name, key. The basic properties of default components can be found using the JavaScript Powered Forms and Form.io SDK sandbox.

This is possible but I want to hide for only default fields not for all form fields is it possible to do it?

@NikhilJikar Okay, I updated the answer. Let me know if it helps or not. If you find it useful, please select the answer "Accepted" as this is how the site mechanism works, which also applies to other people.
